# Connection refused:h2:1521 with docked-compose.yml file

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, h2

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  marketapp:
    image: computer_store
    container_name: computer_store
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:h2:tcp://h2:1521/storedb
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: sa
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: as

    depends_on:
      - h2db

  h2db:
    image: buildo/h2database:latest
    restart: always
    hostname: h2
    ports:
      - "1521:1521"
    volumes:
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initdb.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initdb.sql
```

My initdb.sql file:

```
USE storedb;

-- User table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
    `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `surname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

-- Product table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
    `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `price` BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

-- Insert Users
INSERT INTO `user` (`name`, `surname`) VALUES
    ('Ahmet', 'Ak'),
    ('Osman', 'Kara'),
    ('Akif', 'Dege');

-- Insert Products
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, `price`) VALUES
    ('Macbook Pro', 24000),
    ('Lenova', 12000);
```

initdb.sql file:

I get this error when 'use storedb' in initdb.sql file. I get this error:
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "STOREDB" not found; SQL statement:
spring-market-app-h2db-1 | USE storedb

Without 'use storedb' in initdb.sql file. I get this error:
Connection refused: h2:1521"

Comment: Very likely the `storedb` does not exist in the h2 database server. Can you add something like `create database 'storedb'`?

Comment: when ı add this :
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS storedb;
USE storedb;

I get this error:
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE DATABASE[*] IF NOT EXISTS STOREDB "; expected "OR, FORCE, VIEW, ALIAS, SEQUENCE, USER, TRIGGER, ROLE, SCHEMA, CONSTANT, DOMAIN, TYPE, DATATYPE, AGGREGATE, LINKED, MEMORY, CACHED, LOCAL, GLOBAL, TEMP, TEMPORARY, TABLE, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, HASH, SPATIAL, INDEX"; SQL statement:

Comment: I do not work with H2 containers. You may want to revert to documentation how to properly setup the database.